# Why does Linkedin pull an image from the image folder instead of the url from the og tag?

Tags: html, tags, linkedin-api

I quite new to coding and having trouble with the og tag when sharing on social media. Both facebook and Twitter pull the right url image but for some reason Linkedin pulls another image from my images folder (a send icon). I truly can't work out what I am doing wrong. I have tried to reset the cache from linkedin and have used their inspector tool. You can see the image it pulls. It gets all the other og tag data fine.

I have tried the Linkedin inspector, I have cleared the cache and can't see what else I need to do. Any help would be truly accepted as I am trying to launch a new product.

Comment: **Show us** your `og:` HTML.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this in the end. I will leave how here in case other newbies are stuck.

I placed the sharing image on my shopify site to get the url to use for the image. As I placed it on shopify, they automatically increased the image size to 488 x488 pixles which was too big for linkedin. Linkedin then just took another image.